# Score facebook friends

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, sorting

```
    $app_using_friends = $facebook->api(array(
        'method' => 'fql.query',
        'query' => 'SELECT uid, name FROM user WHERE uid IN(SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND is_app_user = 1'

      ));

       echo '<pre>';
      print_r("query results:");
      print_r($app_using_friends);
      echo '</pre>';


    foreach($app_using_friends as $fl){

        echo "<li>".$fl['name']."</li>";        
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE fb_id = " . $fl['uid']);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
       $test = $row{'fb_score'};
       echo "score:".$row{'fb_score'}."<br>";
    }
    }


query results:Array
(
  [0] => Array
  (
    [uid] => 100004375809
    [name] => Brat
  )

  [1] => Array
  (
    [uid] => 100005832212
    [name] => Vit
  )

  [2] => Array
  (
    [uid] => 100005832323
    [name] => Ala
  )

)
```

> Brat
>   score:1
>
> Vit
>   score:46
>
> Ala
>   score:20

How can you sort by score?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution 1

You can add those result into array and use `usort()` function to sort the array. It should look like this:

```
$list = array();
foreach($app_using_friends as $fl){      
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE fb_id = " . $fl['uid']);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $list[] = $row;
    }
}

function mycmp($a, $b) {
    if ($a['fb_score'] == $b['fb_score']) return 0;
    return ($a['fb_score'] > $b['fb_score']) ? -1 : 1;
}

// Performing the sort
usort($list, mycmp);

var_dump($list);
```

### Solution 2

You can join all the friend's ID and do only one MySQL pass. It should look like this:

```
$friend_id = "";
foreach($app_using_friend as $value) {
    if ($friend_id != "") $friend_id .= ","
    $friend_id .= $value['uid'];
}

// Query
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE fb_id IN (" . $friend_id . ") ORDER BY fb_score DESC");
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in index.php on line 149  usort($list, function($a, $b) {

Comment: What is your PHP version? Older PHP version does not support closure.

Comment: @user3149249, I have updated my answer to support older PHP version. For me, I strongly suggest you to use the second solution which is cleaner and less MySQL query pass.

Comment: Solution 2: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in index.php on line 143 $friend_id .= $value['uid'];

Comment: Is it possible to paginate results in a div. And if so how it could do that.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Order by:`

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE fb_id = " . $fl['uid'] . " order by fb_score");
```